# App development linking interface builder with my code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This might be a stupid question but after making an UITextEdit in interface builder, how do I actually use it in code?

I'm imagining something like

```
UITextEdit textedit;
```

But how do I then link that to ensure the text edit updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reading a [basic tutorial on iOS development](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html). Trust me, it will be worth your time.

Comment: I'll have a look, I'm using xCode 3 though so certain features are a bit out of date. I have a menu, buttons and can load more then one screen so I have been using it for a bit

Comment: @izuriel Snow Leopard version of Mac OSX. Can't upgrade unless I get Lion can I?

Comment: @lucas My bad :D Didn't pay that close attention to the version numbers. Yea it appears XCode 4 is for Lion only.

Comment: Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard is available for manual download from the iOS Developer Centre.

Comment: If on 10.6.8 or .9, one has access to the Mac app store and therefore Xcode 4.2 for snow leopard.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard, but `IBOutlet` is what you need to learn from that documentation.